# Scriptaculous / Prototype modal window

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, lightbox, modal-dialog, scriptaculous

I would like to make a modal window using prototype and scriptaculous. I was wondering if there is any site that has a tutorial or if anyone could kinda give me some idea where to start. (I don't want a prebuilt one)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Control.Window, here are some others I have found:

1. http://okonet.ru/projects/modalbox/index.html (very nice, and free)
2. http://prototype-window.xilinus.com/download.html (looks pretty good)
3. http://dzone.com/snippets/javascript-dialog-box-based (not packaged, just a code snippet)
4. http://www.nickstakenburg.com/projects/lightview/ (slick! but not free)

More image oriented:

1. http://www.huddletogether.com/projects/lightbox2/ (a classic!)
2. http://www.doknowevil.net/litebox/