# Modal dialog in Magento

Tags: forms, magento, modal-dialog

I am new to Magento. I am using Magento 1.6.1 and I am trying to create a modal subscription form (category newsletter subscription) before customers can see category view. I can create custom blocks and have subscriptions on the category page but I want it as a modal form to ensure the user completes the subscription before he can be allowed to view the category page. How can I achieve this in Magento?

Regards
Suk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento uses Prototype and Scriptaculous javascript libraries by default. Here's a question about making a modal form using them. [Scriptaculous / Prototype modal window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2069423/scriptaculous-prototype-modal-window)